# Do the stochastic integrals of two processes with same distribution also have same distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to prove: Given two continuous functions $f,b$, and $X$ a stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, satisfying
$X_t=\int_0^tb(X_s)ds+\int_0^tf(X_s)dW_s$,  if $\hat X$ is a stochastic process on $(\hat\Omega,\mathcal{\hat F},\hat
P)$, which has the same distribution as $X$, then we have $\hat X_t=\int_0^tb(\hat X_s)ds+\int_0^tf(\hat X_s)d\hat W_s$.

But I don't know if the left parts have the same distribution, or each the integral has the same distribution.

I tried to prove the stochastic integrals are distributed the same by assuming $X$ and $\hat X$ are simple processes but failed.

Comment: Is the only regularity we have on $b$ and $f$ continuity?

Comment: b and f are already given, and are also Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** See Kurt's comment below for a way to take this construction and account for the continuity constraint.

---

You cannot prove it because it is not true. Take $\hat{X}$ and $W$ two independent Brownian motions and define $X_t = \int_0^t \mathrm{sgn}(W_s) dW_s$. Seeing that $X_t$ is a continuous martingale with linear quadratic variation, Levy's characterisation theorem tells us it is a Brownian motion, so it agrees in distribution with $\hat X$. Define
$$\hat{Y} = \int_0^t \mathrm{sgn}(\hat{X}_s)dW_s$$
Then, $\hat{Y} \neq \hat{X}$ because $\langle \hat{X}, Y \rangle_t = 0 \neq t = \langle X \rangle_t$.

Comment: This counterexample doesn't seem to satisfy that $X_t = \int_0^t f(X_s) dW_s$ for any function $f$.  There is also an assumption in the problem that $b$ and $f$ are continuous, which $\text{sgn}$ wouldn't satisfy (although that can possibly be resolved by approximating it with a continuous function)

Comment: @user6247850 missed the continuity condition, thanks for pointing it out. However, I'm not sure I understand your other point. The way I read the question seems to imply that $X$ and $f$ are given, no?

Comment: @user6247850 . $f,g$ are surely not all continuous functions. An $X_t$ that satisfies that SDE for any $f,g$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @KurtG. Right, I wasn't suggesting the SDE should hold for all $f, g$, but that the counterexample should demonstrate some $b, f, X$ such that $X_t = \int_0^t b(X_s)ds + \int_0^t f(X_s)dW_s$.  We can take $b \equiv 0$ so it's just $X_t = \int_0^t f(X_s)dW_s$, but the example in this post (as I understand it) only has $X_t = \int_0^t f(W_s)dW_s$, and $X_t \ne W_t$.

Comment: Jose Avilez' classic can be used to construct a counter example to OP: Take $b\equiv 0\,,f\equiv 1\,.$ Then $X_t$ is the BM $W_t\,.$ As $\hat{W}_t$ we take the BM
$$
\hat{W}_t:=\int_0^t\operatorname{sgn}(W_s)\,dW_s\,.
$$
And as $\hat{X}_t$ we take $X_t\,.$ They have then the same distribution. If OP's conjecture were true we had
$$
X_t=\int_0^tf(X_s)\,dW_s=\int_0^tf(X_s)\,d\hat{W}_s=\int_0^tf(X_s)\operatorname{sgn}(W_s)\,dW_s
$$
but since $f\equiv 1$ this means $X_t=W_t=\hat{W}_t$ which is not true: When $W_t<0$ then the increments of $\hat{W}_t$ and $W_t$ have opposite signs.

Comment: @KurtG. wonderful! Thanks for fixing the counterexample to account for the constraints :)